# convertRect fromView not returning correct frame after rotation

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I have a problem I've run into with the `UIView` method `convertRect: fromView:` method. Here is the situation: 
I have an overwritten the `UIView` class to create a view that rotates with the user's movement(very similar to the TaskRabbit spinner). To create the rotation, over I added an additional view to my subclassed view, and I rotated that view. The rotated view contains additional subviews that obviously rotate with the rotated subview. The problem is, after the subview has been rotated, I need to find where those additional subviews are, with respect to the **original overritten view** - not the rotated view. To do this, in my `UIView` class, I have the following:

```
[self convertRect:currentView.frame fromView:rotationView];
```

However, when I print out the frame of the converted rect, the coordinates are not accurate. Has anyone run into this issue where the `convertRect: fromView:` isn't accurate after the view is rotated?

**Edit**

Specifically, about the points being not accurate, I can't even see the relationship between what is should be and what it is-ie off by an specific angle, x/y flipped etc. For example, the point that should be (25, 195) is returned at (325.25, 273.16)

Comment: What do you mean by not accurate? Like a couple pixels off or is the x/y swapped or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are rotating your views by applying a transform to them (either a `CGAffineTransform` to the view or a `CATransform3D` to the layer). This is what is causing the problem with your frame. The documentation for [UIView frame](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame) says:

> **Warning** If the `transform` property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

As you've already seen, the value of the frame is undefined. You can still use the `center` and `bounds` properties though.

Comment: While that may be related, it still doesn't solve the issue. I have tried the same process using [self convertPoint: currentView.center fromView: rotationView] and still get the wrong point.

Comment: This is probably because the view that you are converting from has an undefined frame.